# Monitoring remotely Biztalk 2006 & 2010 Servers using C# and WMI

Tags: c#, monitoring, biztalk, distributed, health-monitoring

I need implement application (in SysTray) that monitors Biztalk 2006 and 2010 servers (Biztalk 2006 installed in Windows 2003 machines, Biztalk 2010 installed in Windows 2008 machines) using C#.

I thinks I should use WMI. Perphaps any API or another components ??

It will be useful any sample good source code (codeplex, codeproject, sourceforge, etc)

I want install my Monitor application in a PC Windows XP without Biztalk installed, and monitoring Biztalk Server 2006 - 2010 (installed in Windows 2003 or Windows 2008).

edit: from MSDN forums

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/biztalkgeneral/thread/7b35ad84-d800-4b7d-9f13-3855c3a2c2e1

•   Monitoring a BizTalk Server is complex, because there is a huge amount of information to monitor. This is best done with dedicated tools such as System Center Operations Manager , for instance. Or alternatives like IPM (formerly known as BizMon), Minotaur , or FRENDS Helium .

However, if you do need special-purpose software to monitor a BizTalk Server while logged on, you will need to make use of the various programming interfaces available to you:

•   Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM : (sample code for instance this post ) 
For basic application management (schemas, maps, pipelines and orchestrations) you could use these interfaces to monitor missing application ressources, for instance.

•   The BizTalk WMI Provider : (samples ) 
For more advanced platform management (hosts, host instances, send and receive handlers, etc.) You would use these interfaces to implement watchdogs around running host instances, for example.

•   Microsoft.RuleEngine and Microsoft.BizTalk.RuleEngineExtensions : 
For creating, importing, exporting or deploying BRE policies and vocabularies. You would use these interfaces to create custom rule set tracking interception.

Beyond that, there are a myriad of other assemblies and programming interfaces for dedicated tasks on BizTalk, be it deployment and installation, managing running or suspending instances, etc.

In fact, this vast diversity in programming interfaces and paradigms is what prompted Maxim Labelle to create a unified BizTalk Management Automation Layer as part of our PowerShell provider for BizTalk Server .

Another option is using PAL with Performance Counters you can capture.

More edit:
for access remotely using WMI. My question is about access remotely to Biztalk 2006 Server using WMI

[using WMI to uninstall applications remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577338/using-wmi-to-uninstall-applications-remotely)

http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/3396385/Remote-access-with-WMI.aspx

updated: (Biztalk 2006 installed in Windows 2003 machines, Biztalk 2010 installed in Windows 2008 machines)

edited: open source project BizTalk Control Center (BCC)

biztalkcontrolcenter.codeplex.com

Comment: You might want to check out the open source project BizTalk Control Center (BCC) http://biztalkcontrolcenter.codeplex.com

Comment: http://www.biztalk360.com is another option you can look into. As a founder my opinion will be biased, so I'll let you explore yourself via the product tour page http://www.biztalk360.com/Content/Tour.aspx?q=uap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As its name suggests BizTalk is a *server* platform. This means that there usually is not any actual logged on user session available for a [task notification icon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511448.aspx) to be useful.

Monitoring a BizTalk Server is complex, because there is a huge amount of information to monitor. This is best done with dedicated tools such as [System Center Operations Manager](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/en/us/operations-manager.aspx), for instance.

However, if you do need special-purpose software to monitor a BizTalk Server while logged on, you will need to make use of the various programming interfaces available to you:

- [Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.biztalk.explorerom%28BTS.20%29.aspx):

For basic application management (schemas, maps, pipelines and orchestrations). You could use these interfaces to monitor missing application ressources, for instance.

- The [BizTalk WMI Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560069%28v=BTS.70%29.aspx):

For more advanced platform management (hosts, host instances, send and receive handlers, etc.) You would use these interfaces to implement watchdogs around running host instances, for example.

- [Microsoft.RuleEngine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee269606%28v=bts.10%29.aspx) and [Microsoft.BizTalk.RuleEngineExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee255387%28BTS.10%29.aspx):

For creating, importing, exporting or deploying BRE policies and vocabularies. You would use these interfaces to create custom rule set tracking interception.

Beyond that, there are a myriad of other assemblies and programming interfaces for dedicated tasks on BizTalk, be it deployment and installation, managing running or suspending instances, etc.

In fact, this vast diversity in programming interfaces and paradigms is what prompted me to create a unified [BizTalk Management Automation Layer](http://psbiztalk.codeplex.com/#biztalkfactory_management_automation) as part of our [PowerShell provider for BizTalk Server](http://psbiztalk.codeplex.com/).

Powershell includes native support for *remoting*, in that it allows to run commands against target machines. This allows the PowerShell provider for BizTalk to be used to [remotely administrate a BizTalk Server Group](http://biztalkmessages.vansplunteren.net/2009/11/24/biztalk-remote-administration/), without having BizTalk installed on the local machine.

You might want to check-it out.

Comment: any api or wrapper in codeplex (or another site) for do more easyly Biztalk monitoring...

Comment: I want too do monitoring: Biztalk 2006 installed in Windows 2003 machines, Biztalk 2010 installed in Windows 2008 machines. My client is Windows XP without Biztalk.